# Is sprintf incompatible with sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Say I have this:

```
class Account
  ...
  property :charge, Decimal, :precision => 7, :scale => 2
  ...
  classy stuff
  ...

  def self.balance(prefix)
    x = Account.get(prefix.to_sym).order(:fields => [:charge]).sum(:charge)
    sprintf("%5.2f", x)
  end
end
```

*(Edit: The value of all :charge fields is 0.13E2 (0.1E2 + 0.3E1). This is correctly returned. Only in a View does it seem to get borked from `sprintf`)*

In IRB `Account.balance(:AAA)` returns `=> "13.00"`

if I call `Account.balance(:AAA)` from a view I get *TypeError at /accounts
can't convert nil into Float*

`Account.balance(:AAA)` works anywhere I call it *except* in a view. If I remove `sprintf("%5.2f", x)` I get `0.13E2` in my view. *(using `Account.balance(:AAA).to_f` in a view gives me `13.0`)*

Is sinatra incompatible with `sprintf`? or am I not understanding how to use `sprintf`?

*(Edit: This is the offending view:)*

```
<section>
  <% @accounts.each do |account| %>
    <article>
      <h2><%= account.prefix %></h2>
      <span><p>This account belongs to <%= account.name %> & has a balance of $<%= Account.balance(account.prefix) %>.</p></span>
    </article>
  <% end %>
</section>
```

Comment: Looks like `x` is `nil`. Try and see if that's correct and then figure out why `x` is `nil`; hard to tell from the code you pasted.

Comment: It would seem so. Why then does IRB return the 'correct' result, while a View from sinatra returns the error?

Comment: I can't tell; but the problem doesn't appear to be with `sprintf`. See if you can add some debugging statements to see what is going on. What does `Account.get(prefix.to_sym)` return? etc...

Comment: `prefix = 'AAA'`, `Account.get(prefix.to_sym)` returns the correct account `<Account @id=3 @prefix="AAA" @name="Wanda" @balance=#<BigDecimal:7f94fc45e4b0,'0.0',9(18)> @user_login="wanda">` & `Account.get(prefix.to_sym).orders.all` returns all of the orders. 0o

Comment: Continue from there, what does `Account.get(prefix.to_sym).order(:fields => [:charge])` return? And `Account.get(prefix.to_sym).order(:fields => [:charge]).sum(:charge)`?

Comment: `Account.get(prefix.to_sym).order(:fields => [:charge])` returns an array of all of the orders for the given account with only the charge field loaded, `[#<Order @id=<not loaded>, @charge=#<BigDecimal:7f94fc4309e8,'0.1E2',9(18)>, #<Order @id=<not loaded>, @charge=#<#<BigDecimal:7f94fc4306f0,'0.3E1',9(18)>]` and `Account.get(prefix.to_sym).order(:fields => [:charge]).sum(:charge)`   returns `=> #<BigDecimal:7f94fc40c228,'0.13E2',9(18)> `

Comment: So it seems that the problem was somewhere else in the app 0o thanks so much for your help anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't it make more sense to define `balance` as an instance method rather than a class method? It looks from your example like you're calling `balance` in an `account`-specific way anyway, so why not make it:

```
# the model

class Account
  #...

  def balance
    amount = self.order(:fields => [:charge]).sum(:charge)
    sprintf "%5.2f", amount

    # or the infix version:
    "%5.2f" % amount
  end
end
```

,

```
# the view

...balance of $<%= account.balance %>...
```

I know that this doesn't address `sprintf` per se, but the problem is more likely to be coming from the slightly convoluted lookup than from a built-in method. Even if my specific code doesn't suit your application, it might be worth simplifying the lookup step, even if that involves a few more lines of code.

The advantage of this approach is that there is no doubt that you'll be getting the right `Account` record.

Comment: Something to consider. May change to something like that in the future. Then any account would return its calculated value from a call to balance. But alas, you'er correct... it still doesn't solve the  `sprintf` issue. =(

Comment: I was hoping that if you made this change, the problem would be fixed since I suspect it's more to do with `x` than `sprintf`.

What if you add a temporary debugging line: `p x ; sprintf("%5.2f", x)`? If that shows that `x` is `nil`, then I would say that my answer should fix the problem since it's just an error in the lookup code or database definition (are you sure that the `:prefix` column is never `nil`?)

Comment: So, when I added your debug line, & and pointed safari at the appropriate route, it crashed safari, and shotgun. So I deleted the whole class, retyped it in. and now my method & yours work perfectly.  I have Absolutely no clue why. My only guess is something else in the class was being evil. Although I still need my class method (for other parts of the app that I am not responsible for, I do like your instance method. So I think that I'm gonna use it.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Glad it worked out. Also from experience, even though it shouldn't be a problem, I've found that shotgun sometimes doesn't restart properly and carries through bugs that have been fixed in the source code. It doesn't hurt to manually kill the process and restart shotgun every now and then if issues crop up.

Comment: Yes I have found that as well. Digging in deeper, I think that I have actually figured out what was going on. I recently upgraded to Lion, I only have 2GB of RAM, With Terminal, Safari, my Editor, and Mail open, I only have about ~14MB free. What was happening, I think is that `:charge`, is actually a calculated value itself, and if any of the values where `nil` one of the `:charge` calculator methods would keep trying to get a BigDecimal value... until all of my RAM was eaten up and it would crash.

Comment: I don't know exactly why this was causing problems with `sprinf` I'm not *(yet)* an experienced enough rubyist to figure that out. but adding `return 0.00 if :x.nil?` to my calculator method seems the have fixed everything & reduced the resource overhead significantly. So Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

tested it with a little sinatra app and it worked for me

app.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  @x = 10.23
  erb :index
end
```

views/index.erb

```
<%= sprintf("%5.2f", @x) %>
```

output:

```
10.23
```

ruby 1.9.2 / sinatra 1.3.1

I think there is another error before the sprintf because of your error message:

```
can't convert nil into Float
```

seems like your x is nil. try to be sure that x is not nil there, then sprintf should work as expected.

Comment: I see that in your example you are assigning `x` in the view. Your quick test application also works for me. My app works if I assign `x` in the view. However, pulling `x` from my database *(datamapper)* still returns the same error. I guess this could be a datamapper error, but pulling `from` the database in IRB still returns the 'correct' result, So I would assume that means that some thing in the way sinatra is dealing with the View is not cooperating with `sprintf`.

Comment: updated my answer and it still works for me. maybe you forgot the @ to declare x as an instance variable?

Comment: This little bit of code is being used in a view that lists each account. in the route `@accounts = Accounts.all` is defined. Then in the view `<% @accounts.each do |account| %>` gives me an `<article>` for each Account. There is a line then that *(right now)* calls <%= Account.balance(account.prefix) %> to print the balance of the account *(there is also a helper method called `account_balance` that is exactly the same, using it anywhere but a view produces the 'correct' result. I changed to the `Account.balance` method when I started tracking down this problem)*

Comment: Try to change the variable in the sprintf to something trivial, to see if this works. Maybe you can post the code of the view that I can help more

Comment: So it seems that the problem was somewhere else in the app 0o thanks so much for your help anyway!